# mysql - alternative to IN()

Tags: mysql

I got a table with the columns `| id | postNumber |`. One or more entries belong to one `postNumber`. I need to request the newest entry for each `postNumber`.

```
SELECT `dienstbuch`.`id` , `dienstbuch`.`postNumber`
FROM `dienstbuch`
WHERE `dienstbuch`.`id`
IN (
SELECT max( `dienstbuch`.`id` )
FROM dienstbuch
GROUP BY `dienstbuch`.`postNumber`
)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 2000,10
```

The query takes very long when using on a table with many entries.

How can I improve it?

Comment: Why group by post number ? What are you indexs

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you need max id for every postNumber?

Comment: You are right in identifying the `IN (subquery)` as the cause of problematic performance. I believe that subquery is being executed for each and every row in the dienstbuch table, and that will get expensive for large sets. Consider using an inline view and a JOIN operation, or for your specific query, avoiding the subquery altogether. (See my answer.) An appropriate index will also improve performance, but the real performance problem is (likely) the repeated execution of the subquery.

Comment: Replacing the IN() with a JOIN as described in the answers of spencer7593 and amenadiel fixed the issue! Thank you very much :-) I did actually simplify the query and got to select more fields, thx for including both methods in your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as if you could request the max ID in one straight query

```
SELECT max( `dienstbuch`.`id` ) maxId, postNumber
FROM dienstbuch
GROUP BY `dienstbuch`.`postNumber`
```

But if you are retrieving several fields then it requires a subquery

```
SELECT `dienstbuch`.`id` , `dienstbuch`.`postNumber`, dienstbuch.field1, dienstbuch.field2
FROM `dienstbuch`
JOIN
(SELECT max( `dienstbuch`.`id` ) id, postNumber
FROM dienstbuch
GROUP BY `dienstbuch`.`postNumber`
) maxID
on dienstbuch.id=maxID.id and dienstbuch.postNumber=maxID.postNumber
ORDER BY dienstbuch.`id` DESC
LIMIT 2000,10
```

Comment: +1. NOTE: If the `id` column is unique, then it's not necessary for the inline view (in the second query) to return postNumber. (I made the assumption it was unique.) If postNumber can be NULL, then the result from the second query is slightly different from the OP query, in that it won't return any rows with a NULL postNumber, due to the equality predicate in the ON clause. (The equality comparator could be replaced  by the null-safe comparator  `<=>`).

Answer (score 2):

For better performance, as an alternative to the `IN (subquery)` predicate, you can use a JOIN to an inline view (aka derived table).

For example:

```
SELECT d.id
     , d.postNumber
  FROM dienstbuch d
  JOIN ( SELECT MAX(e.id) AS max_id
           FROM dienstbuch e
          GROUP BY e.postNumber
       ) f
    ON f.max_id = d.id   
 ORDER
    BY d.id DESC
 LIMIT 2000,10
```

That should perform much better, because it's executing the query for the inline view once, rather than executing the subquery for each and every row, which is how MySQL evaluates that `IN (subquery)` predicate.

That's the normal pattern we'd use if we also needed to other columns from the table in the resultset. For your specific query, you don't actually need a subquery at all. You can get an equivalent resultset with this query:

```
SELECT d.id
     , d.postNumber
  FROM dienstbuch d
 GROUP
    BY d.postNumber
 ORDER
    BY d.id DESC
 LIMIT 2000,10
```

This is very likely to perform better, since it avoids the overhead of materializing an inline view, and performing a JOIN operation.

An index `... ON dienstbuch (postNumber,id)` would be the most likely candidate for improved query performance, for both of those queries.

Comment: Is the `JOIN` actually a synonym for inner join or what kind of join is this?

Comment: @Zulakis: yes, `JOIN` is synonymous for `INNER JOIN`. In MySQL, the `CROSS` and `INNER` keywords are entirely optional; `JOIN`, `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN` are all synonymous in MySQL. We typically leave off the `INNER` keyword, but we typically do include the `CROSS` keyword when we've intentionally omitted an ON clause, mostly as a documentation clue for someone reading our statement.